Need to correct a spelling in Odoo Menu but nowhere to be found using Find in Files
I am new to Odoo and began to customize/debug a 3rd party module left by previous developers. One of my task is to correct the spelling from Bill of Landing to Bill on Lading. I am using Visual Studio Code for IDE in my local computer and used the Find in Files for the wrong text. Then changed all the text to the correct spelling. But after I updated the module to reflect the changes​, the spelling in the menu is still incorrect. Can you advise how to solve this? I have a hunch it is in the database.
Here is the process I did, I click New button on the Shipment menu. Then in the next page, I clicked the gear icon, the Print and Duplicate menu will appear. Hovering on the Print menu, the 3rd menu items appears with the wrong spelling. I cannot find this text menu, is it in the database?
Here is the image.

I tried to locate some keywords/tags used in the page but I cannot also find them.

Are you looking to modify the spelling in the Bill of Lading PDF report or in any of the menu items?
